# SQL statement if I don't know how many values in list

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to run this statement in my function I'm writing

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES (?, ?)', (var1, var2))
```

But since it's a function, I won't know how many elements are in the list since I'm calling from the function, so how would I work around that with my values. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: im not sure i understand your question. can you make it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the number of placeholders in the SQL statement to match number of variables.

```
placeholders = ', '.join(['?'] * len(list_of_vars)
sql = 'INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES ({})'.format(placeholders)
c.execute(sql, list_of_vars)
```